# SQL Query execute more records in WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I have SQL Query in which execute data from VIEW. In this Query i have 4 parameters, all parameters data stored in another table. 3 Parameters have data in table and 1 Parameter has no record. In 3 Parameters there are total "1080" records, but this query execute "16000" records.

My SQL Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4

FROM TABLE

WHERE (COL1 IN (SELECT VAL FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'I') OR COL1 = COL1)
AND (COL2 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'P') OR COL2 = COL2)
AND (COL3 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'C') OR COL3 = COL3)
AND (COL4 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'U') OR COL4 = COL4);
```

When i remove OR condition in WHERE CLAUSE Then show empty records.

**Sample Data:**

1080 records

[image]

**Output Data:**

13619 Records

[image]

Comment: share sample data and its expected output

Comment: You will get all data when you use  `OR COL1 = COL1`, exclude all COL1 is `null`

Answer (score 0):

Those are 'tautologies': all the 'and' are short-circuited. You could remove all the `where` and `and` clauses and you'll have same result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM TABLE
```

will give you same result as your current status is like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM TABLE
WHERE (<condition> OR TRUE) -- =TRUE
AND (<condition> OR TRUE)   -- =TRUE
AND (<condition> OR TRUE)   -- =TRUE
AND (<condition> OR TRUE)   -- =TRUE
```

Comment: 4th Column has no record

Comment: @AmmadWasim Please edit your question adding sample data and desired output

Comment: @AmmadWasim No column's titles, as is, tells nothing

Answer (score 0):

placing "OR COL1 = COL1" on your query will result on always true. I believe you wanted to do it this way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4
FROM TABLE
WHERE COL1 IN (SELECT VAL FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'I')
AND COL2 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'P') 
AND COL3 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'C') 
AND COL4 IN (SELECT TO_NUMBER(VAL) FROM RPPARAMLIST where flg = 'U');
```

Comment: with this query it shows empty records Becuase COL4 has no record

Comment: can you give the exact or sample data per column and desired output data?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.col1, t.col2, t.col3, t.col4
FROM table_name t
WHERE EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM rpparamlist 
            WHERE flg = 'I' AND t.col1 = val 
        )
    OR EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM rpparamlist 
            WHERE flg = 'P' AND t.col2 = TO_NUMBER(val) 
        )
    OR EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM rpparamlist 
            WHERE flg = 'C' AND t.col3 = TO_NUMBER(val) 
        )
    OR EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 
            FROM rpparamlist 
            WHERE flg = 'U' AND t.col4 = TO_NUMBER(val) 
        );
```

This query will check for all 4 conditions with `rpparamlist`, then union these 4 results to get the last result